# Confusion on SSL with Node and using cURL

Tags: node.js, ssl, curl

I have setup my secure Node server as:

```
var HTTPSOptions = {
    hostname: config.hostname,
    cert: fs.readFileSync(config.ssl.cert_path),
    key: fs.readFileSync(config.ssl.key_path),
    requestCert: true,
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
    passphrase: config.ssl.ca_key_password
};
HTTPSOptions.agent = new https.Agent(HTTPSOptions);
var httpsServer = https.createServer(HTTPSOptions, app).listen(config.https_port, function () {
    console.info("HTTPS server running on %d", config.https_port);
});
```

I've also generated a `client.key`, `client.crt` and `client.csr` for one of my clients and signed it with the server's `.key` and `.crt`.

Now, I want to connect to my API from a client. Reading on how cURL works, I used:

```
curl --key client.key --cert client.crt:clientPassword mySecureSite.com\api\call
```

This works fine, except that the same code would work if I provide any key/cert or any password, or even if I don't provide any key/cert!

Can someone please enlighten me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've set up your server to communicate via HTTPS with any client. If you wish to limit the clients you communicate with to those with specific certs, you will need to do additional checks in your server code.

[Nate Good wrote a tutorial that might point you down the right path.](http://nategood.com/nodejs-ssl-client-cert-auth-api-rest) Here's a snippet to give you an idea of things to look into:

```
https.createServer(options, function (req, res) {
    if (req.client.authorized) {
        res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"});
        res.end('{"status":"approved"}');
    } else {
        res.writeHead(401, {"Content-Type": "application/json"});
        res.end('{"status":"denied"}');
    }
}).listen(443);
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this a read, seems like exactly what I need./

Comment: So I followed the instruction above, but now my `req.client.authorized` is always false ...